# Spring Boot 3 - Ignore liveness/readiness traces

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-actuator

In a spring boot 3 application. I am getting endpoints calls to /context/actuator/health/liveness and /context/actuator/health/readiness in Jaeger UI.

I searched for a configuration to to have a skip pattern or something similar but failed to find any. How do I ignore API calls to /health/liveness and /health/readiness from being exported to Jaeger?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue using a SkipPattern bean

```java
    @Bean
    SkipPatternSampler skipPatternSampler() {
        return new SkipPatternSampler(Pattern.compile("/actuator/health/(liveness|readiness)"));
    }
```